Symmetric matrices as a $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ representation?
Consider the additive group of $n$ by $n$ symmetric matrices over $\mathbb{C}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$. $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ acts on this by conjugation. Which representation is this, in the language of Fulton and Harris? Any help understanding this representation better would be appreciated.

If I remember their notation correctly it is $\Gamma_{2,0,0,\dots}$

This condition is not invariant under conjugation!

$SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ does not act on symmetric matrices by conjugation; the action of $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ by conjugation decomposes into a direct sum of the trivial representation (scalar multiples of the identity) and the adjoint representation $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ (traceless matrices), which is irreducible.
$SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ does act on symmetric matrices in a different way, not by conjugation but by congruence. This representation is isomorphic to the symmetric square $S^2(\mathbb{C}^n)$ of the defining representation. This means its weights are sums of unordered pairs of the weights of $\mathbb{C}^n$; I think in Fulton and Harris' notation that means its highest weight is $2L_1$ and so this is $\Gamma_{2, 0, 0, \dots }$ as Callum notes in the comments.
